# Implementing And Outputting ArrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So i'm writing a program that find the max,min,total,and average of some people's salaries. I have decided to put the people's names into arraylist string and their salaries into arraylist integers. My problem is being able to output the maxsalary,minsalary,averagesalary which i want as a double, and the total salary because when i run my program it gives each of the values as 0.

here is my code:

```
package employees;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Persons {
    //method to add salaries
    //find average and min and max
    int maxSal;
    int minSal;
    int totalSal;
    double averageSal;
    public ArrayList people;
    public ArrayList salaries;

    public  int totals() {
        //int totalSal = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < salaries.size(); i++)
             totalSal += salaries.indexOf(i);
        return totalSal;
    }

    public int minSal() {
         //minSal = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i < salaries.size(); i++) 
              if( minSal > i) 
                   minSal = i;
         return minSal; 
    }

    public int maxSal() {
         //maxSal = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i < salaries.size(); i++)
              if( i > maxSal)
                   maxSal = i;
         return maxSal;
    }

    public double averageSal() {
         double averageSal =((totalSal)/5);
         return averageSal;
    }
 }

//mainmethod
package employees;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PersonsTest {

     Persons persons;
     Job job;

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Persons g = new Persons();

         ArrayList<String> people = new ArrayList<String>();
         people.add("Ron");
         people.add("Don");
         people.add("Armin");
         people.add("Ferry");
         people.add("Ben");
         ArrayList<Integer> salaries = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         salaries.add(50000);
         salaries.add(40000);
         salaries.add(70000);
         salaries.add(55000);
         salaries.add(90000);   

         System.out.println(g.maxSal);
         System.out.println(g.minSal);
         System.out.println(g.averageSal);
         System.out.println(g.totalSal);    
     }
}
```

Comment: Your class contains some flaws. I would suggest a reverse aproach for this. Check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html (DoubleSummaryStatistics) and think about how you could refactor your class to utilize this builtin Java functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There are some logical mistakes in your implementation.

First off all you should use

```
int maxSal;
int minSal;
int totalSal;
double averageSal;
```

within your methods and init them with 0.

**Edit**
It's not necessary to init them. By default they are set to 0. As you can see here: 
[Primitive Datatypes in JAVA](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Second mistake is within your totals-method.

```
totalSal += salaries.indexOf(i);
```

If you have a look into the api:

> indexOf method returns the index of the **first occurrence**

change it to:

```
totalSal += salaries.get(i);
```

**Better way to do your stuff:**

You don't have to implement it on your own. There are libs fore that:

**EDIT 2**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections; 
import java.util.stream.*;  

    ArrayList<Integer> salary = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    salary.add(50000);
    salary.add(40000);
    salary.add(70000);
    salary.add(55000);
    salary.add(90000);



    System.out.println(Collections.min(salary));
    System.out.println(Collections.max(salary));

    /*Without java 8*/
    int sum = 0;
    for (Integer e : salary) sum += e;
    System.out.println(sum);
    /*AVG*/
    double avg = sum / salary.size();
    System.out.println(sum);
    System.out.println(avg);
```

Comment: _init them with 0_. No need for this. The default values for these primitives are 0.

Comment: i totally agree with that. But if he deletes the object fields he may not understand why there is no need to init them. will expand my answer. ty

Comment: i am using it without java 8, what does the salary represent because i used the arraylist salaries and it doesnt seem to take that when i replaced salary with salaries

Comment: I have init them to 0 but i commented them out because i thought it served no purpose

Comment: I added the salary to my solution. I just run it on my PC. It seems to work. if you want we could chat. (have a look at the new max and min)